# Namespace problems in XSL transformation of XHTML

Tags: xhtml, namespaces, xslt-1.0

Whilst transforming XHTML to XHTML with XSL I have a problem with namespaces. Consider as an example input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>Remove this</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the following transformation does not work (e.g. does not remove the `<p />`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="copy">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this one does:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="copy">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:p" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem and question is: How can I change the XSLT so that I do not have to add prefixes to all the XHTML elements and it still get to match them? From what I tried so far, adding a default namespace like `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />` does not achieve this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can I change the XSLT so that I do not have to add prefixes to all the XHTML elements and it still get to match them?
```

This is possible, but I would recommens defining the namespace and using the preefix in referring to elements in this namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='p']" />
```

**Warning**:

This technique can be safe only if it is guaranteed that there arent two elements with the same `local-name()` but in different namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will follow it. Your solution also works, though I guess I should have added to my question that I am looking for a shorter and more convenient way than using prefixes. :-)

Comment: @hielsnoppe, You are welcome. Using prefixes is the shortest and most readable solution.